# Home, Back, Menu, Search buttons not working

Tags: buttons

Suddenly, Home, Back, Menu, Search buttons are not working.  No amount of rebooting or taking out the battery work.

I saw somewhere that clearing the Dalvik cache might work, but I got as far as getting adb running, only to discover I need root access to clear the Dalvik cache.

Comment: What device are you using? Could be relevant, I suppose.

Comment: Samsung Galaxy with Spring

Answer (score 1):

This means the provisioning (first run) got somehow interrupted.

To fix this, run the following command from a root terminal or from `adb shell`:

`sqlite3 /data/data/com.android.providers.settings/databases/settings.db "INSERT INTO secure (name,value) VALUES ('device_provisioned','1');"`

and then reboot.

Comment: He doesn't have root.

Comment: Ohh! Also, it's not a fresh installation, so what could possibly screw them up?